# Application start-up in ESP32-C3

Tags: esp32, riscv, bare-metal

I was trying to develop a custom application for a esp32-c3 board, without using FreeRTOS. For this reason I was trying to understand the application startup process when using the second stage bootloader (I know how to do when using "direct boot mode", with only the first stage one).

This is the official documentation:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.3/esp32c3/api-guides/startup.html#first-stage-bootloader

However, by looking at the hello_world app in the edf examples, I found that the following function "call_start_cpu0" is defined both in:

esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader/subproject/main/bootloader_start.c

and in:

esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c

The only difference is that in second case it has the IRAM_ATTR.

My questions are:

1. which one is used ? Both are compiled and they are found in bootloader.elf and hello_world.elf (to be download in the flash).
2. are there instructions about creating a custom application without RTOS but still using the second stage bootloader?

Thanks for your help.